# ¿Cómo sumar vectores representados por tuplas en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Digamos que tengo que sumar 2 vectores de n-dimensiones. ¿Cuál es la forma pytonica de sumarlos directamente?

Por ejemplo en R^3, pero sin estar limitado a R^3,

```
a = (123.45, 23.45, 1.0)
b = (45.678, 56.78, 5.0)
```

(Obtener `(169.128, 80.23, 6.0)`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Si intentas lo obvio, obtienes un generador:

```
>>> (sum(x) for x in zip(a, b))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7faf248e20f8>
```

Así que puedes convertirlo en tupla directamente:

```
>>> tuple(sum(x) for x in zip(a, b))
(169.128, 80.23, 6.0)
```

En todo caso, te recomiendo que en su lugar uses [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array((123.45, 23.45, 1.0))
>>> b = np.array((45.678, 56.78, 5.0))
>>> a + b
array([ 169.128,   80.23 ,    6.   ])
```

Answer (score 4):

Intenta con :

```
S = [i+j for i,j in zip(a,b)]
```

Comment: Porque le pusieron -1?

Comment: La respuesta es buena y diferente a lo que se ha dicho hasta ahora, no hay razón para votar negativo. ¡Gracias Gaby!

Answer (score 3):

Otra forma usando los módulo `operator` e `itertools`:

```
from itertools import izip, starmap
from operator import add

add_tuples = lambda a,b: tuple(starmap(add, izip(a, b)))
```

Usando el ejemplo suministrado:

```
>>> a = (123.45, 23.45, 1.0)
>>> b = (45.678, 56.78, 5.0)
>>> print(add_tuples(a, b))
(169.128, 80.23, 6.0)
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Otra forma **pythonica**:

```py
a = (123.45, 23.45, 1.0)
b = (45.678, 56.78, 5.0)

c = tuple(map(lambda x, y: x + y, a, b))
print(c)
```

`map` toma un elemento de cada uno de los iterables que se le pasan, lo que permite ahorrarse el zip.

En Python 3.x, map retorna un `generator`.

En Python 2.x podría utilizarse `itertools.imap` en vez de `map` para tener un resultado siempre coherente y no generar una lista intermedia.

Resultado

```
(169.128, 80.23, 6.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

En principio:

```
>>> map(sum, zip(a, b))
```

Ahora bien, en python3 obtendrás un generador, así que si quieres obtener una tupla o una lista:

```
>>> tuple(map(sum, zip(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

El lenguaje de programación *Python* es uno de los más usados en el ámbito científico y educativo y eso se debe a sus librerías y *APIs* específicas para todo lo relacionado al cálculo científico, te recomiendo que entres a *[SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/)* y revises esta gran galería de librerías muy interesantes entre las cuales, se encuentra *NumPy*, la cual ya te recomendaron, y *Matplotlib* que también es muy útil para lo que quieres hacer, solo es cuestión de investigar un poco en su documentación y veas cuál se acerca más a lo que quieres hacer.

Recuerda que una de las ventajas de *Python* es la gran cantidad de librerías que resuelven mucho de los problemas a los cuales nos enfrentamos en el ámbito educativo y laboral. Siempre que tengas que hacer algo en específico seguramente ya alguien creo una librería que al usarla muy probablemente te ayude a minimizar el tiempo para resolver el problema.

Comment: binvenido a es.stackoverflow quizas desee leer esto http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Saludos